# What are the advantages of using REST instead of SOAP?

Tags: rest, soap

In which situation, we need to use REST (Representational state transfer) and Why ?
That looks similar to SOAP, except the fact that REST has seperate URL for each method. Whereas in SOAP we can call everything using single URL.

Comment: This says it all -> http://geekandpoke.typepad.com/geekandpoke/2009/11/service-calling-made-easy-part-1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from this [link](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/tip/REST-vs-SOAP-How-to-choose-the-best-Web-service):

> REST vs. SOAP
>
> Multiple factors need to be considered when choosing a particular type
>   of Web service, that is between REST and SOAP. The table below breaks
>   down the features of each Web service based on personal experience.
>
> REST
>
> The RESTful Web services are completely stateless. This can be tested by restarting the server and checking if the interactions are
>   able to survive.
>   Restful services provide a good caching infrastructure over HTTP GET method (for most servers). This can improve the performance, if
>   the data the Web service returns is not altered frequently and not
>   dynamic in nature.
>   The service producer and service consumer need to have a common understanding of the context as well as the content being passed along
>   as there is no standard set of rules to describe the REST Web services
>   interface.
>   REST is particularly useful for restricted-profile devices such as mobile and PDAs for which the overhead of additional parameters like
>   headers and other SOAP elements are less.
>   REST services are easy to integrate with the existing websites and are exposed with XML so the HTML pages can consume the same with ease.
>   There is hardly any need to refactor the existing website
>   architecture. This makes developers more productive and comfortable as
>   they will not have to rewrite everything from scratch and just need to
>   add on the existing functionality.
>   REST-based implementation is simple compared to SOAP.
>
> SOAP
>
> The Web Services Description Language (WSDL) contains and describes the common set of rules to define the messages, bindings,
>   operations and location of the Web service. WSDL is a sort of formal
>   contract to define the interface that the Web service offers.
>   SOAP requires less plumbing code than REST services design, (i.e., transactions, security, coordination, addressing, trust, etc.) Most
>   real-world applications are not simple and support complex operations,
>   which require conversational state and contextual information to be
>   maintained. With the SOAP approach, developers need not worry about
>   writing this plumbing code into the application layer themselves.
>   SOAP Web services (such as JAX-WS) are useful in handling asynchronous processing and invocation.
>   SOAP supports several protocols and technologies, including WSDL, XSDs, SOAP, WS-Addressing
>
> In a nutshell, when you're publishing a complex application program
>   interface (API) to the outside world, SOAP will be more useful. But
>   when something with a lower learning curve, and with lightweight and
>   faster results and simple transactions (i.e., CRUD operations) is
>   needed, my vote goes to REST.